# Sonarqube stage in jenkins pipeline fails with 403 error

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube

have a pipeline job which keeps failing on Sonar Quality Gate stage with the below error:

> [Bitbucket] Build result notified
>   org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 403 on
>   http://illinXXXX:XXXXX/api/qualitygates/project_status?analysisId=XXXXXXXX
>       at org.sonarqube.ws.client.BaseResponse.failIfNotSuccessful(BaseResponse.java:34)

What's more strange, another pipeline from the same MS, is passing that stage. They both are using the same Sonarquebe user and token, and the same stage syntax.

Sonarqube version: 6.7.1 (build 35068).

Notes:

- I also tried [this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-48540), but it didn't work.
- The logger for org.sonarqube.ws.client not working. it doesn't write anything to the log.

Comment: Please summarise in the Q&A what you tried.

Comment: Go into `Manage Jenkins -> System Log` and add a new logger for `org.sonarqube.ws.client` that logs in `DEBUG` level. Otherwise there is no way to magically "guess" what's wrong here. It could be literally everything from the token being wrong, to a reverse proxy, to a plugin issue to an SSL certificate issue (although it looks like you are using `http`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem:
The execution user/group had permissions to run  “Execute Analysis”
Solution:
Update the default template with permissions and push to projects (Bulk Apply Template)